# How do I sort #region:s with a one click operation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We use #region #endregion blocks a lot in our project.

Is there some vs or extension trick to have them sorted easily?

Actually, I do not know why they came out of order to start with. They did.

Comment: There might be a plugin for DevExpress' Refactor! tool that would do this - nothing out of the box, but it'd be quite easy to create.  If you have "standard" blocks that you use repeatedly, the tool also supports moving members into those regions and will create them in your specified order, but it won't automatically resort existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you expected

Select a region of code and press `ctrl+k and s` then select #region and then specify your region name.

Comment: There is no region name, I want to sort the regions by name.

Comment: I think you can't; even i googled some VS extension.there is nothing.